Segmentation Fault error in c for some unknown reason
Wondering why I get this error Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) when running my code. I am trying to code blackjack and my code is probably very inefficient lol. But if anyone can help, thanks in advance!
I pinpointed the area where it happens and it happens where my "ERROR HAPPENS HERE" comment is. If you have any questions about the rest of the code, ask below.
Edit:
Here is my Code in text:
char conv(int num)
{
    // Converts numbers into respective deck values
    char c = 'h';
    if (num == 1)
    {
        c = 'A';
    }
    else if (num == 11)
    {
        c = 'J';
    }
    else if (num == 12)
    {
        c = 'Q';
    }
    else if (num == 13)
    {
        c = 'K';
    }
    else if (num == 10)
    {
        c = 't';
    }
    else
    {
        c = num + '0';
    }
    return c;
}

int deal(void)
{
    // Deals Card between 13 and 1
    int card = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    return card;
}

int hit(void)
{
    int card = deal();
    string c = "he";
    // Converts cards into printable format
    if (card != 10)
    {
        c[0] = conv(card);
        c[1] = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        c[0] = conv(card);
    }
    // Prints card
    printf("┌─────────┐\n");
    printf("│%s       │\n", c);
    printf("│         │\n");
    printf("│         │\n");
    printf("│         │\n");
    printf("│         │\n");
    printf("│         │\n");
    printf("│       %s│\n", c);
    printf("└─────────┘\n");

    // Returns card number dealt
    return card;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    bool play = true;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: casino [money]");
        return 1;
    }
    bool round = true;
    while (round)
    {
        // Draws cards
        srand(time(NULL));
        int pcard1 = deal();
        int pcard2 = deal();
        int pscore = pcard1 + pcard2;
        int dcard1 = deal();
        int dcard2 = deal();
        int dscore = dcard1 + dcard2;

        // Converts card numbers into a printable format
        string p1 = "hello";
        if (pcard1 == 10)
        {
            p1 = "10";
        }
        else
        {
            p1[0] = conv(pcard1);
            // ERROR HAPPENS RIGHT HERE
            p1[1] = ' ';
        }

        string p2 = "hello";
        if (pcard2 == 10)
        {
            p2 = "10";
        }
        else
        {
            p2[0] = conv(pcard2);
            p2[1] = ' ';
        }

        string d1 = "NULL";
        if (dcard1 == 10)
        {
            d1 = "10";
        }
        else
        {
            d1[0] = conv(dcard1);
            d1[1] = ' ';
        }
        string d2 = "NULL";
        if (dcard2 == 10)
        {
            d2 = "10";
        }
        else
        {
            d2[0] = conv(dcard1);
            d2[1] = ' ';
        }


Please edit to include your code as text rather than an image.

Are you in CS50, with string as a typedef of char *?

deal isn't defined.

How can you assign to p1[0] if p1 is NULL?

p1[0] == *(p1 + 0) == *p1  If p1 is NULL then you're dereferencing a null pointer, Undefined behavior ensues. A segfault is one possible outcome.

Do not post images/links of code. Images are often chopped, leave out necessary info, can't be downloaded. Use code block(s). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? To create a code block: In your editor, select the [desired] text. Copy to clipboard [with ctrl-c]. Edit the question here [using the edit button]. Scroll to bottom. Enter \``on a separate line [to start a code block]. Thenctrl-vto paste in the text. Then, another```` line [to end the code block]. Then, click on the save button.

Sorry, just uploaded my complete code. Even with changing my variables set to NULL to a random strong like "hello", I still get a segfault

Similarly for string d1 = NULL;and d2. There is no memory allocation, and it can't be derefernced.

Well, if your pointer points to a string literal, then modifying that is... you guessed it... undefined behavior.

If you need to modify a string, then you need to allocate memory (dynamically or otherwise) and copy or concatenate with strcpy or strcat.

@Chris what do you mean by that? Sorry I am very new to coding

Explaining string handling in C from scratch is a little beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. I suggest you get a good book.

And with string c even if you did allocate memory, it can't be passed for printf() format spec %s because it has no string terminator: it isn't a valid C string.

My guess is that you are using the CS50 course, although you only showed incomplete code. Just follow the course.

@Jeremy Don't learn programming from videos. Learn from a reputable book. The latest question edits are still undefined behavior because you are not allowed to modify a string literal. You could use an array, but the general approach you're using right now is still a big mess. Consider my answer below as a simpler and cleaner solution. Also notice how each function does one thing that's useful and re-usable.

You have all kinds of problems stemming from a misunderstanding of pointers and strings in C. I recommend you just use a table of string literals instead:
#include <stdio.h>

const char* card_name(int card)
{
    static const char* names[] = {
        "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"
    };
    return (card >= 1 && card <= 13) ? names[card-1] : NULL;
}

void display_card(int card)
{
    const char* name = card_name(card);
    if (name)
    {
        printf("┌─────────┐\n");
        printf("│%2s       │\n", name);
        printf("│         │\n");
        printf("│         │\n");
        printf("│         │\n");
        printf("│         │\n");
        printf("│         │\n");
        printf("│       %-2s│\n", name);
        printf("└─────────┘\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
   {
       display_card(i);
   }
}

Note that this handles layout of the string symmetrically. The string format specifiers are using a field width specifier. The %2s will pad the string out to a minimum of 2 characters by adding spaces on the left, while %-2s will add spaces on the right instead. This allows you to use single- or double-character (e.g. 10) names.
The way the table works is it's just storing an array of string literal pointers. The return line here is using the conditional operator, which is essentially evaluating to:
if (card >= 1 && card <= 13) {
    return names[card-1];
}
return NULL;

That is just a safety in case you pass an invalid card value. It ensures you don't try to index outside of the array.

MSVC handles NULL passed to printf() format spec %s gracefully (output is (null)), but not to sprintf(), when it crashes.

It could easily be "" instead. I suppose the paranoid should test the result. I'll update accordingly.

You can't expect a beginner to interpret the answer. What has paranoia to do with it? You should test the answer yourself.

There was nothing wrong with calling that function in the way I am calling it in the answer. Every card is in a valid range, which is a reasonable precondition of calling the function.

Ok wait I pretty much get how this works (it just maps each card number to the array of characters representing a deck) , but when I store conv(card) into a character value, I get the error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Well, yeah. A char represents a single character, while card_name returns a pointer to a char, which happens to be a string literal. You can't copy a pointer value into a char value and expect anything meaningful.

There's not such thing as a string in plain C. (We're not talking about C++, which is a different beast.) So, it's quite obvious that you have a hidden typedef (by means of an #include not shown in your example code or a compiler directive) associating the string pseudo-type with a char * type (ie. a "char pointer") (a pointer just represents the address of a cell in the memory of your computer/process).
When you do something like string p1 = "hello"; (if that really means char *p1 = "hello";) you're asking the compiler to allocate a memory area (this is usually done at compile time, not at run time) and to save inside it a sequence of individual char constants ('h', 'e', etc), followed by a special char (a '\0) that means "this is the end of the sequence". That's what we usually call a "string constant" (even when there are not, technically speaking, strings in C). After that, the variable p1 will contain a pointer to the first of these chars (that is, the address of the memory cell that contains the 'h'). That's OK.
Then, when you do something like p1[0] = conv(pcard1); or p1[1] = ' ';, you overwrite the first or the second of these characters. That's not entirely bad, but you may be hitting the problem already noted by @Chris: you shouldn't overwrite the so called "string constants", because... well, because they're supposed to be CONSTANTS. The exact overcome of doing that depends on the specific implementation (it's "undefined behaviour") (the compiler may be using a read only area for storing the sequence, etc).
Note: just in case, be aware that doing string d1 = "NULL"; (which, in this case, COULD work with some implementations) is totally different than doing string d1 = NULL; (which wouldn't allocate any space for your subsequent chars, and would assign a NULL pointer, which is a pointer to nothing, to d1).
Edit. As a (relatively) simple solution, you may replace the
   string p1 = "hello";  // aka. char *p1 = "hello";

with a predefined array of fixed size, whose content CAN be safely modified later:
   char p1[10] = "hello";

Doing so, you're explicitly reserving space for 10 chars (actually, for 9 useful chars plus 1 terminator) and you're asking the compiler to initialize this space with the sequence of chars enclosed between quotation marks. This way, p1 will contain an array of chars (and not a pointer to the first char in a sequence stored apart), but you'll use the variable in the same way as you did before.
Just be careful of not exceeding the defined size (10 chars, in my example, and that includes the '\0' terminator). Also, I think your line:
   p1[1] = ' ';

is meant to "terminate the string" (ie. to mark its really used length), and it should be replaced by:
   p1[1] = '\0';

